# A bounded Borel measurable function is Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:R\to R$ be a bounded Borel measurable function,Endow $R$ with Lebesgue measure $\mu$. Suppose there are constants $M>0$ and $0<a<1$ such that for any $y>0$ has
$$
\mu(\{x\in R :|f(x)|>y\})<M/y^a
$$
Prove that $f\in L^1(R,\mu)$

My solution

assume $|f|<B, A_n=\mu(\{x\in R :|f(x)|>1/n\}$,

so$\int_R |f|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{A_n}|f|\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}MBn^a$
But right side is not a constant,can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following fact can be very useful when relating $L^p$ and weak-$L^p$ spaces: $$\int_R |f|^p \, d\mu = p \int_0^\infty y^{p-1}\mu(\{ |f| > y\}) \, dy.$$

Take $p = 1$.  Since $f$ is bounded you get $$\int_R |f| \, d\mu = \int_0^{\|f\|_\infty} \mu(\{ |f| > y\}) \, dy \le \int_0^{\|f\|_\infty} My^{-\alpha} \, dy.$$

Comment: thank you can you tell me how to prove the first equality or give me some reference?

Comment: If you are willing to use Tonelli's theorem the proof is rather simple: $$\int_R |f|^p \, d\mu = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{|f|} py^{p-1} \, dy d\mu = p \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty y^{p-1} \chi_{\{y < |f|\}} \, d\mu dy.$$ The inner integral is just $\mu(\{|f| > y\})$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $0 \le f \le 1.$ Then

$$\int_\mathbb R f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\{2^{-n}< f \le 2^{-(n-1)}\} }f\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-(n-1)}\mu(\{f>2^{-n}\})$$ $$ \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-(n-1)}[M/(2^{-n})^{\alpha}] = 2M\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[2^{\alpha-1}]^n < \infty.$$